# ConcurrentModificationException building Android XML with data binding

Tags: android, android-databinding

`Error:cannot generate view binders java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` occurs when trying to set an `ObservableBoolean` value in XML.

XML:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Soy Milk"
    android:onClick="@{() -> model.useSoy.set(true)}"
/>
```

Model:

```
public ObservableBoolean useSoy = new ObservableBoolean(false);
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I got it running by calling a seperate setter method.

XML:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Soy Milk"
    android:onClick="@{() -> model.setUseSoy(true)}"
/>
```

Model:

```
public ObservableBoolean useSoy = new ObservableBoolean(false);

public void setUseSoy(Boolean useSoy){
    this.useSoy.set(useSoy)
}
```

Comment: But better use `boolean` instead of `Boolean`